# Unix check mkpasswd against that stored in /etc/shadow

Tags: unix, encryption

I want to validate a password (of user mark).

sudo cat /etc/shadow | grep mark
mark:$6$bvY9mYW3$XdKkg0tluBghADi45V.RG1dTfctvnYdU.5J40nW8bh4UqpxtHp8uF8Zxx8U9mth9w0dvmgtVUrAtydQCvsivA1:16304:0:99999:7:::

From the result ($6) I understand that the password is generated using a sha-512 encryption algorithm with bvY9mYW3 as the salt.

When I generate the hashed password using

mkpasswd -m sha-256 -S bvY9mYW3 -s

I get $6$bvY9mYW3$XdKkg0tluBghADi45V.RG1dTfctvnYdU.5J40nW8bh4UqpxtHp8uF8Zxx8U9mth9w0dvmgtVUrAtydQCvsivA1

It is almost the same but I am missing the tailing :16304:0:99999:7::: part

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The [`mkpasswd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/mkpasswd.1.html) utility creates a hash from a password, but [`/etc/shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/shadow.5.html) doesn't just contain hashed passwords; it also contains other information including login names and details about the age of a password. Each line should have a total of 9 fields separated by colons, but some of the fields can be left empty (and often are).

For example, `16304` is the number of days since Jan 1 1970 when the password was created (i.e., 22nd August 2014), 99999 means the password doesn't need to be changed for 99,999 days (about 274 years), and 7 means you'll be given a week's notice when it's time to change your password. (Although you'll probably be dead by then.)

If you're verifying a password, you could just examine the first two fields (name and password hash), but you should really check the other fields to make sure it hasn't expired.